# Optimal way of pairing up string values java

Tags: java, string, data-structures

I want some way to pair `String` values and pass it on as a data structure. Any recommendations? Would a `Map` work? The issue that I'm having with a `Map` is that not all strings will be paired in this context, only a few of them. I need to have all the strings and if there exists one, it's string pair as well. If anything lacks clarity, let me know.

Comment: Do you mean, you want a list of elements, which are either a pair of strings, or just one string?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` can be used, with a special value for string without pair.

Comment: I had thought of doing something like this, but was wondering if there  is a better way.

Comment: Most map implementations do allow null values and there's a method that can be used to check for key's existance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is probably not the best way, but what I sometimes use is a duplex type structure that is similar to Python's tuple.

I build a generic structure like so:

```
class Duplex<T,T> {
 private T item1, item2;
 public Duplex(T one){
  item1 = one;
 }
 public Duplex(T one, T two){
  item1 = one;
  item2 = two;
}
 //Getters + Accessors
}
```

Doesn't have to be generic, but it lets you reuse it for other situations.

I haven't used maps before though, so those might actually be better.

Comment: a java map is equivalent to a python dict.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I usually use the above Duplex structure for returning a pair of related values.

Comment: @Woot4Moo To be more precise, I think Python `dict` is (more-or-less) equivalent to Java `HashMap`. Java standard library has a bunch of other `Map` implementations too, and things like Apache Commons and Guava have more.

Answer (score 0):

A map will give you the key value pairing that you want.  What you may want is something like this:

```
class MyPair  
{  
    String first;  
    String second;  
   // Equals and Hashcode
}
```

Now it is up to you to decide the inner parameters of your `MyPair` class.
    Map pairings = new HashMap();

Answer (score 0):

Since most of your elements will be one String I suggest turning your pairs into Strings as well.

```
 public static final String SEP = "\uFFFF"; // not a valid character by definition.

 public static String pair(String a, String b) {
     return a + SEP + b;
 }

 public static String[] split(String str) {
     return str.split(SEP);
 }
```

Comment: if you have a lot of pairs, be care of performance with this solution.  Concatenation and split are expensive.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier & faster to store strings in an array or separate fields. This solution just doesn't make any sense

Comment: The memory consumed is less that wrapping two Strings in an array or class.  Without more information I cannot say what is best.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way is to use arrays.

```
List<String[]> pairs = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

...

```
pairs.add(new String[]{"first", "second"});
pairs.add(new String[]{"pairless"});
```

Or use whatever container you want, `List` here is just an example, point is `String[]`.

Note: Using plain array is sort of "quick and dirty", it's more "proper" to create a custom "Pair" class. Especially if you have methods which operate on sigle pair, it makes sense to create a class to contain them. In that class you can still internally use this kind of array to store 1 or 2 (or some other number of) items.

Comment: How would I go about between bringing pair classes and strings together in one collection and dealing with them separately?

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not sure what you mean by that question... But generally in Java, "bringing togethers" different types is done by creating a class which does it.